# C++ cannot convert Student* to DYNVECTOR<Student,24>::Node* in initialization

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to create an iterator for my dynamic vector class that i've implemented,

The thing is I keep getting this error when I try to initilaize some student class for testing
purposes on some assignment for the iterator, I cannot figure out why Im having this error wasted alot of hours on it and its impossible to figure out why this error occurs..

Here is the code

```
some edit
```

Here is the main function that im trying to use that takes the iterator from my class

```
some edit
```

Just in the intiliaze of the DYNVECTOR class in the main my code fails , I keep on getting
the error:

error: cannot convert 'Student*' to 'DYNVECTOR <Student, 24>::Node*' in initialization
Iter(T *N ) : _pointer(N) { }

EDIT: please guys focus on this part:
inputIterator begin() { return inputIterator(pa);}
this is what is causing the error, the functionality of the push back function and other funtions are still in progress but that is not the reason causing this error.

Comment: @user4581301 Im trying to create a virutal length vector, which functions actually need to support iterators and the use of dynamic arrays at the same time and the only thing i thought of is creating iterator using the nodes in order to support all kind of classes, like T which i put in the constructor of the iterator in my class which is as example Student, so i want to create the consturctor that takes iterator of T values and saves the data of it into the actual vector, and I have to implement this iterator without the usage of STL.

Comment: @JeJo Yes i have this function already finished, but this is not the main problem here thanks for the notice.

Comment: Lose the nodes. You want a dynamic array of `T`. The iterators could reduce down to something as simple as a `using iterator = T*`. The hard part will be managing the size of the array.

Comment: @user4581301 How can i use this practice of iterator ? If i have to implement it dont I need to do the nodes part aswell? doesn't that depend on the STL? and if i just use T* how can i take the next element?

Comment: @user4581301 The thing is im trying to pass a student to the constructor of the iterator that takes any type of classes to the value of the node so the student will be there in the value and the next of it will be the next student in order to use it in my iterator functions, which also makes sense in the begin and end part of the iterator, but the thing is it says it cannot make the student to node but im requesting from it to create it in the val of the node not to node itself, that is why i cannot understand why this bug occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

```
inputIterator begin() { return inputIterator(pa);}
```

is calling `inputIterator`'s constructor

```
Iter(T *N ) : _pointer(N) { }
```

with a pointer to a `T`, a `T *`. `Iter` takes `T *` happily, but it tries to store that `T *` into `_pointer` and `_pointer` is defined as

```
Node *_pointer;
```

which is NOT a `T *`. The assignment fails because the types don't match.

## The Naive Solution

Make the types match. This means you have to pass in a `Node *`. Bad news: `DYNARRAY` doesn't have any `Node *`s to give it. Naive solution fails.

## The Proper Solution

Throw out `Node`. `Node` is useful if you have a linked list. You don't have a linked list. Kill it. Make it dead. Clean up the mess.

```cpp
class DYNVECTOR
{
    // no nodes
    class Iter // directly uses T pointers
    {
    public:
        Iter(T *N) :
                _pointer(N) // types match now        
        {
        }
        T& operator*() const
        {
            return *_pointer; // simpler without Node, no?
        }
        T* operator->() const
        {
            return _pointer; // simple
        }
        Iter& operator++()
        {
            _pointer++; // dead simple
            return *this;
        }
        Iter operator++(int)
        {
            Iter tmp = *this; 
            _pointer++; // yawn-city
            return tmp;
        }
        bool operator==(Iter const &rhs) const
        {
            return _pointer == rhs._pointer; // unchanged
        }
        bool operator!=(Iter const &rhs) const
        {
            return _pointer != rhs._pointer; // unchanged
        }
    private:
        T *_pointer; // T *, not Node *

    };
private:
    size_t someCap, length; //, initCap; don't see the point of initCap
    T *pa; // unchanged
public:
    typedef Iter inputIterator;
    DYNVECTOR():
        someCap(Capacity), // Still not sure what Capacity is for, so I used
                           // it here instead of magic number 24
        length(0),
        pa(new T[someCap])
    {
        // used initializer list instead.
    }

    inputIterator begin()
    {
        return inputIterator(pa); // unchanged
    }
    inputIterator end()
    {
        return inputIterator(&pa[length]);  // iterator to one past the end.
                                            // just like std::vector
    }
    template<class Iter>
    DYNVECTOR(const Iter &begin, const Iter &end): // far more versatile if const references
        DYNVECTOR() // delegate basic set-up to default constructor
    {
        for (Iter pointer = begin; pointer != end; pointer++) // loop unchanged
        {
            push_back(*pointer);
        }
    }
    // make uncopyable (for now anyway) See Rule of Three 
    // linked below for why
    DYNVECTOR(const DYNVECTOR & ) = delete;
    DYNVECTOR& operator=(const DYNVECTOR & ) = delete;
    
    ~DYNVECTOR() // for my own testing. left as example
    {
        delete[] pa; // clean up allocated storage
    }
    
    void push_back(const T & newb) // for my own testing. left as example
    {
        if (length == someCap) // need more space
        {
            int newCap = someCap * 2; // double the size
            // you might need to do something different like 
            // int newCap = someCap + Capacity;
            // There's no way for me to know. 
            // The rest should be right though.
            T* newArr = new T[newCap]; // allocate bigger array
            for (size_t index = 0; index < length; index++)
            { // copy old array into new
                newArr[index] = pa[index];
            }
            delete[] pa; // discard old array
            pa = newArr; // use new array
            someCap = newCap; // update capacity
        }
        pa[length] = newb; // insert new item
        length++; // update counter
    }
};
```

[Documentation on the Rule of Three and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You cannot write complex and efficient C++ unless you understand these rules. Learn them or consign yourself to being a hack.

Comment: This elaborates my whole problem and is more than enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you deal with objects it is bad practice to do:

```
DYNVECTOR<Student, 24> students;
```

It should be:

```
DYNVECTOR<Student*, 24> students;
```

Secondly you never created a constructor for your DYNVECTOR how do you expect the object to be created??

Comment: That is a bad suggestion. There are many other better option in c++.

Comment: first of all the line in main is the line that making the error that I specified , It has more stuff in there which i can edit my main post and show , but I dont think that its necessary because the line that I mentioned is from the assignment itself and not my practice I didn't write it but its a test to my implementation, I have edited my post for the main function.
I have created a constructor for the DYNVECTOR if u focus on my class, but its not the thing that causes this error, its the begin iterator function, if you can focus on that it will be helpful.

Comment: @OdayHajYehia the problem is you are passing a pointer to a `Student` into a function that needs a pointer to a `Node`. You are headed in the wrong direction and unfortunately no one can advise you on how to get on the right path because you're following two paths and we don't know which is the correct path. It looks like you are making a dynamic array AND a linked list at the same time.

Comment: @user4581301 I thought he was trying to create a linked list of students???

Comment: It's OK to be confused. The code is about half way between a linked list of `Node<Student>` and a dynamic array of `Student`. It has all of the `Node` infrastructure in the iterators, but none of the support needed to make the `Node`s work in `DYNVECTOR`. And then there's the name. `DYNVECTOR` doesn't sound much like a linked list.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I understand what you mean , but im not passing the student to the function that takes pointer to node but to the constructor of the iterator that takes any type of class ( T ) which in my opinion makes sense , not really sure though.

Comment: @YunfeiChen No i wasn't trying to create linked list of students , im trying to send array of the students to the iterator implementation in order that the node val will hold students and the next student etc.. so i can use it in the functions that takes iterator as parameters..